# C Valgrind - Source and destination overlap in memcpy

Tags: c, valgrind, memcpy

I'm new to c programming and I'm writing a simple client server application. I get this message:

```
 Source and destination overlap in memcpy(0x41f0beb, 0x41f0258, 69141077)
    ==9522==    at 0x402D9A9: memcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
    ==9522==    by 0x8049C13: message_to_buffer (message.c:92)
```

Here is the specific code:

```
case CT_ENTRY://100
{
    int c=(2+2+4+strlen(msg->content.entry->key)-1+4+4+strlen(msg->content.entry->value->data));
    char *offset=malloc(c);
    *msg_buf=offset;
    memcpy(offset,&opcode,2);
    offset+=2;
    memcpy(offset,&ctype,2 );
    offset+=2;
    int ks=strlen(msg->content.entry->key);
    int ksc=host_to_net(ks);
    memcpy(offset,&ksc,4);
    offset+=4;
    memcpy(offset, msg->content.entry->key, ks);
    offset+=ks;
    int l=host_to_net(get_time());
    memcpy(offset,&l,4);
    offset+=4;
    int ds=host_to_net(msg->content.entry->value->datasize);
    memcpy(offset,&ds,4);
    offset+=4;

    // this line here!
    memcpy(offset,msg->content.entry->value->data, msg->content.value->datasize);

    return c;
    break;
```

The offending line is

```
memcpy(offset,msg->content.entry->value->data, msg->content.value->datasize);
```

Can anyone please explain why this is happening? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the `datasize` value of `69141077` is correct?

Comment: You are copying almost 70 megabytes of data, is that really correct?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem. It should be only a few bytes. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `memmove` instead of `memcpy` if the source and destination memory blocks overlap.

Comment: But why are they overlapping? They're completely different variables.

Comment: @UserConscious Even if the variables are different, the areas the _point to_ may not be.

Comment: So how do I solve the problem, since I want to copy the contents of data to offset?

Comment: @UserConscious: From valgrind output it seems that the size is suspiciously large ~69MB.

Comment: You should triple check your code before using memmove instead of memcpy. Usually the problem is a buffer overflow and you do not want to overlap memory blocks.

Answer (score 5):

You are telling `memcpy()` to copy 69141077 bytes of data. This looks to be much bigger than the size you have actually allocated in `offset` (unless those strings are really **huge**).

So, it's a buffer overflow. Check that the contents of `msg->content.value->datasize` match the size you're calculating when allocating `offset`.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The man page for `memcpy()` says:

> The memcpy() function copies n bytes from memory area s2 to memory
>   area s1. If s1 and s2 overlap, behavior is undefined. Applications in
>   which s1 and s2 might overlap should use memmove(3) instead.

Comment: The OP has stated that his areas *should not* overlap, so the advice to use `memmove()` doesn't really solve the problem.